# Is it possible to index an infinite number of timelines in a universe-agnostic manner?

Tags: parallel-universe, rick-and-morty

One of the plot devices used in Rick and Morty is the concept of an infinite number of alternate (i.e. parallel) universes. The characters in the show seem to use some sort of multi-universal indexing system to assign codes to these alternate universes.

Can such a system exist? Wouldn't it would have to be relative to one's own universe, thus making it incapable for this system to be universe-agnostic?
Is this actually possible, or just one of the lovable absurdities of the show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To form the Counsel of Ricks,

> A few thousand versions of me had the ingenious idea of banding together, like a herd of cattle or a school of fish, er, those people who answer questions on Yahoo Answers...

They're probably the ones who assign the codes to those alternate universes but remember, not all of those universes have a Rick, just *most:*

> Most timelines have a Rick and most Ricks have a Morty.

This reminds us that nothing is an absolute in R&M land. *Can such a system exist?* Surely, but rest assured that in at least one universe, the answer's no... I mean yes. Wait...

<sub>source: S01E10 *Close Rick-counters of the Rick Kind*</sub>

Comment: those people who answer questions on Yahoo Answers...or some other site where people answer sci-fi questions?

Comment: What finite subset of an infinite set can qualify as a majority of that set? I'm pretty sure your quote indicates that there *are* infinite Ricks.

Comment: @RyanVeeder - [Infinity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710291/does-an-equation-containing-infinity-not-equal-0-or-infinity-exist) is not a word that should be used lightly. It can only be said that as you *approach* infinity, *most* universes have Ricks.

Comment: Each universe has to have objective "co-ordinates" within the multiverse; otherwise the characters couldn't travel back to their home universe, and couldn't reliably re-visit places...and as far as indexing, there are plenty of systems used in our world to catalog an ever-expanding set of information. As far as who actually sets the conventions for naming, I assumed that is the council of Ricks...so...by the logic of the show, it seems possible?

Comment: @anaranjada - I've tried to address your concerns in an edit. I think all I ended up doing was cronenberging myself into a corner.

Comment: I'm entirely unfamiliar with the show, but I see that there aren't any dubious mathematical claims in the new answer, so have a +1 for your efforts.

Comment: One logical way to order the timelines  would be to start with the ones belonging to the original members of the Council of Ricks, and then increase the count with every new Rick they meet. What the letter C in "C137" stands for, though, is anyone's guess.