# Are the Council of Ricks known by the general public?

Tags: rick-and-morty

Rick himself is of course infamous across the entirety of the universe. One presumes that Ricks from alternate universes are mostly similarly famous/infamous in turn. But is the Council of Ricks known to the general public?

I ask this because in a recent question, someone theorized that the universe code designations were assigned by the Council of Ricks. But if that is true, that would seem to necessitate the public being aware of the Council in order for the information to be distributed. If the Council decides on the codes and don't disseminate them to the public, then every time Rick tells folks which universe he is from with a designation, it would be meaningless to them. Finally, I don't see Rick using anything developed by the Council if he can at all help it. So is the Council known to the general public of other universes?

Comment: Was there some concrete argument behind the theory? It is just as likely (and much simpler) that universe designations are akin to, say, country names, and anyone who travels between them is aware of them.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116621/24024 I have no idea how to insert this link via phone sorry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Doubtful.

The whole point of the [Council of Ricks](http://41.media.tumblr.com/2c334645d1b9020fa1e5370b22c5b446/tumblr_inline_o1d8pq494v1timrep_500.jpg) is to protect all Ricks. Telling everyone in the multi-verse that countless Ricks all congregate in one location would be rickdiculous.

Even though the location of the [Citadel of Ricks](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel_of_Ricks) is supposedly a very well kept secret, we see how far the Galactic Federation is willing to go to track down a Rick and his terrorick allies:

The *[Mortywaves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvJ-JHLcBmg)* generated by all the Mortys at the citadel would no-doubt conceal the *geniuswaves* generated by the Ricks, which would make the Ricks much more difficult to locate (by their brainwaves at least).

But it would just be too ricksy to let everyone know about the council.

---

And as for the universe code designations, every Rick in every dimension no doubt came up with the very same codes for every other dimension. How every regular person seems to understand Rick when he tells them what dimension he's from is never really explained.

Comment: Good enough for me.

Comment: what do we mean by 'regular person'. Hasn't Rick only ever explained what Dimension he is from to those individuals who are aware of multiple Dimensions?